# Metaballs: Material duplicating issue

Tags: materials, metaballs

I'm using metaballs to make a cheap fluid like flow effect using the particle emitter. I am using a curve as a guide for force.
I also have another smaller version of the same thing in the scene, and would like to use a different material for that metaball.
However, if I spawn another metaball it instantly takes the material of the first metaball and is unable to be changed.
These fluids won't interact as the curves are separated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Use a texture that has an object defining it's coordinates. You can use as many colors as you want in the colorramp. You could also do something nifty with shaders where you use the colorramp to be the factor in a mix shader. Or you could use a noisy gradient if you wanted, as shown.

Look at the node setup.

Comment: Thanks thats helpful, I guess all metaballs in the scene are linked. I was hoping there was a way to have separate groups or collections or something.

Comment: I agree. There should be an option where metaballs could ignore the ones not in their 'group', or something to that effect. This solution would get tricky if you were not in the same plane.